# Dymola: OPC server grayed out

Tags: opc, dymola

I am using Dymola [Ran as Administrator]

I have installed OPC Core Components: `D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020a\toolbox\opc\opc\private\win64\OPCCoreComponents\OPC Core Components Redistributable (x64).exe`

I have installed Matrikon OPC Server Simulation.

I have put in environment variables:

[image]

In Dymola I am using this:

[image]

[image]

This is the simple code I am running in Dymola:

[image]

OPC server is grayed out still.

Simulation is working.

Comment: Seems to be a bit unfortunate timing, but Dymola 2021x discontinued OPC support: https://www.3ds.com/fileadmin/PRODUCTS/CATIA/DYMOLA/PDF/Dymola-2021x-release-notes.pdf -> page 46, section 3.6.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use an older version of Visual Studio.

Here are the limitations of the OPC functionality according to Dymola User Manual Volume 2 in Dymola 2019 FD01:

- You must run Dymola with administrator rights to be able to run the OPC server.
- Currently only the solvers Lsodar, Dassl, Euler, Rkfix2, Rkfix3 and Rkfix4 are
  supported.
- *Only Visual Studio 2008, 2010, and 2012 compilers are supported.*
- Dymosim with OPC server is always built as a 32-bit application.
- OPC Server cannot be combined with Export model as DLL.

Comment: installing Visual Studio 2012 with Dymola 2019 worked